BsonDataReader iteration of a list
I have a bson file that I exported from mongo using mongodump. I want to read that data in using C# and create JSON objects from it.
I can read in the first object and transition it to a string, which i can then move to a POCO.
However I dont see the iterator that would move me to the next item in the data.
        using (System.IO.FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
            memStream.SetLength(fileStream.Length);
            fileStream.Read(memStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)fileStream.Length);

            memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            bool bKeepReading = true;
            using (var reader = new BsonDataReader(memStream))
            {
                
                                   
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                var sw = new StringWriter(sb);
                using (var jWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
                {
                    jWriter.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
                    jWriter.WriteToken(reader);
                }


            }
        }

This yields a string that i can use to get what i want. What advances to the next object in the reader?

Why not just https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeFromBson.htm ?
